# How to create 0 or 1 if value is the first occurrence and appearing in the latest year in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame where I need to create new column with 0 and 1 based on the new occurrence of column value.

Data frame input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value_text': ['type1', 'type1', 'type1','type2','type2','type3','type3','type4','type4','type5','type6'],
                   'year': [2016,2017,2021,2018,2021,2019,2021,2020,2021,2021,2021]})


     value_text  year
0       type1  2016
1       type1  2017
2       type1  2021
3       type2  2018
4       type2  2021
5       type3  2019
6       type3  2021
7       type4  2020
8       type4  2021
9       type5  2021
10      type6  2021
```

Based on this need to create new column with 0 and 1 considering value_text that appeared only one time that too in the current year.

here in the result data frame type5 is appeared only in current year and didn't appeared in previous years. basically trying to identify new occurrence and creating value 1 else 0.

Result:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'value_text': ['type1', 'type1', 'type1','type2','type2','type3','type3','type4','type4','type5','type6'],
                   'year': [2016,2017,2021,2018,2021,2019,2021,2020,2021,2021,2021],
                   'value': [0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1]})
```

output:

```
     value_text  year  value
0       type1  2016      0
1       type1  2017      0
2       type1  2021      0
3       type2  2018      0
4       type2  2021      0
5       type3  2019      0
6       type3  2021      0
7       type4  2020      0
8       type4  2021      0
9       type5  2021      1
10      type6  2021      1
```

Comment: Why `type4` is 1?

Comment: Can you make your request clearer please?

Comment: Can you expand your example to show another case where a current year entry is assigned a value of 1, and a negative case where a current year entry does *not* get a value of 1?  I think if you have two entries `type6` in 2021 then they would get value 0, but it's not clear.

Comment: @Steve Thanks for your interest, updated with new example.

Comment: @sophocles Thanks for your interest, updated with new example

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh  I have updated question with new example, idea is to create value 1 only if the value is appearing first time that too in current year. here type5 is 1 because it is appearing only once and year is 2021

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `duplicated` to create a boolean mask `m1` to identify the values which are not duplicated. Similarly, create another boolean mask `m2` by comparing the year column with the current year, now take the logical `and` of `m1` and `m2` and assign the result to column `value`

```
m1 = ~df['value_text'].duplicated()
m2 = df['year'].eq(pd.Timestamp('now').year)
df['value'] = (m1 & m2).view('i1')
```

---

```
>>> df

   value_text  year  value
0       type1  2016      0
1       type1  2017      0
2       type1  2021      0
3       type2  2018      0
4       type2  2021      0
5       type3  2019      0
6       type3  2021      0
7       type4  2020      0
8       type4  2021      0
9       type5  2021      1
10      type6  2021      1
```